# Most efficient way to pass data to a std::valarray from a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, valarray

What's the most efficient way to set the data from a `std::vector` to a `std::valarray`? Say we have `std::valarray<double> my_valarray;` and `std::vector<double> my_vector;` and we want to copy the data across from `my_vector` to `my_valarray`:

Option 1 (using `valarray` constructor and copy assignment):

```
my_valarray = std::valarray(my_vector.data(), my_vector.size());
```

Option 2 (resizing and copying):

```
my_valarray.resize(my_vector.size());
std::copy(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), std::begin(my_valarray));
```

The question arises because in both cases it looks like the complexity is **O(2n)**. In the first case the data is copied to temporary `valarray` during construction (one allocation + one pass to copy the data) and then on assignment to the final object (one allocation + one pass to copy the data). In the second case there is one allocation + one pass for initialisation of all elements to zero and another pass to copy the data. Do the move semantic of C++11 applies in the first case making it require only one allocation and one pass to copy the data?

Comment: *O(2n) = O(n)*. I.e. It has linear time complexity.

Comment: Why do you use valarray in the first place?

Comment: @Columbo Because I'm doing some vector maths with the valarrays and that's what they are good for. Don't like implementing lambdas when you can use valarray built-in operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, move semantics applies in the first case, because `std::valarray(my_vector.data(), my_vector.size())` is an rvalue and a move assigment operator is defined for the `valarray` class(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator%3D).

Comment: We know that. The problem is that every element in [`my_vector.data()`, `my_vector.data() + my_vector.size()`) is copied.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is more efficient. The reason is that `std::valarray::resize` zero-initializes all data. But i would assume that any compiler worth it's salt would optimize that redundant zero-initialization away.

You can't prevent copying from the vector to the valarray, there is no way to transfer the ownership of the memory block from my_vector to my_valarray.